# Is there any way to skip the pages - Google custom search API?

Tags: linkedin-api, google-search, google-custom-search

I am using `Google Custom Search api` in my application, sample search [link](http://www.google.com/custom?num=100&cof=CX%3AX-Ray-LinkedIn%3B&cx=009462381166450434430%3Aecyvn9zudgu&q=nodejs&btnG=Search) for searching profile in LinkedIn.

#### Requirement

I need to `skip` first ten pages and get the `next ten` pages. Basic idea is to skip first 1000 records, I want the next 1000 records.

#### Question

Is there any way to skip the first 10 pages and get the next ten pages in the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though not specifically mentioned in the API description, the [Google GSA Search Protocol Reference](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/xml_reference/request_format.html#1076971) is pretty explicit about this limitation:

> The maximum number of results available for a query is 1,000, i.e.,
>   the value of the start parameter added to the value of the num
>   parameter cannot exceed 1,000.

However, if all you need is more than 1,000 records (as you indicated) you can structure your query to return a well-defined non-overlapping subset of potential results, then piece together the overall result.

A simple example would segment results by date. For the custom query you posted, appending something like `&sort=date:r:20100101:20101231` would return 1,000 results from the year 2010. If you repeat this for 2011, you would have a total of 2,000 results.